# Schedule Oracle Reports and export to XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a report that I need to run everyday @ 00:00 and export all the information from the table to a specific  location with a specific name.

Example:

```
    select * from my_table 
where date between  SYSTIMESTAMP -2  and SYSTIMESTAMP -1
```

and to export this to file date.xml.

Is this possible from Oracle SQL Developer or do I need other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Oracle version so I assume 10 or 11.

To schedule your process you just have to create a job and schedule it. The job has to run your script (which can be a function or a stored procedure).
Here is the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm#i1033533

To write to a file you can use the spool command in SQL. Here you can find the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm

It's really simple to use.

```
spool @path/nomefile
la tua query
spool off
```

Obviously, the machine from which you run the script must have write permissions on the machine where you're going to write the file (I say this because I often forget to check out).

To create an XML is slightly more complex and a little long to explain here but there is a nice post on the community of Oracle that explains it and makes a simple and practical example: https://community.oracle.com/thread/714758?start=0&tstart=0

If you do not want to use a job in Oracle you can write a .Sql file with the connection commands, the spool command and your query and schedule it on the server machine on which you intend to set as a simple command sqlplus.